# Geometric interpretation of weighted least squares

Tags: linear-algebra

I really like geometric interpretation of least squares that least squares solution is merely a projection of Y on the column span of X (which is very logical since column span of X describes all vectors that could be achieved as linear combination of columns)

Is there similar geometric interpretation for weighted least squares?